# set current page in laravel 6 paginate without ?page=2

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-6

I need so set current page in laravel pagination without get page number from get parameter.

**the thing some like this:**

```
$fetch = Post::paginate()->setCurrentPage(3);
```

**It's possible to do?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to override the [Paginator::currentPageResolver()](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html#method_currentPageResolver) to change the way the page is determined:

```php
Paginator::currentPageResolver(fn() => 10);

$users = User::paginate(); // you now will be on page 10
```

Unfortunately there is no way to reset or retrieve the original function set in the [PaginationServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0b12ef19623c40e22eff91a4b48cb13b3b415b25/src/Illuminate/Pagination/PaginationServiceProvider.php#L40) as the property is protected and there's no getter.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$posts = Post::where('status', 1);
$posts_temp = $posts->paginate(2);

if(!$request->has('page')) {
  Paginator::currentPageResolver(fn() => $posts_temp->lastPage());
}

$posts = $posts->paginate(2);
```